# Como buscar el mayor en el ciclo for

Tags: javascript

```js
document.getElementById("comparable").addEventListener("click", mayor);

function mayor() {
  var numeros = [],
    ingresar = prompt('Ingresa los números, separados por comas', ''),
    j = 0;
  var c = ingresar.replace(new RegExp(',', "gi"), " ").split(" "),
    var v = c.length;
  for (; j < v; j++) {

  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="comparable" value="Comparar" />
```

**Hasta el momento, recibo los números en la `función`, les quito la `coma` y los meto en un `array`. Luego mi idea es `recorrerlo` y el **mayor de todos sera devuelto**, pero como verifico el mayor en un *ciclo for*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno, aunque no lo especificas, supongo que tu función tendrá que hacer algo con el **número mayor**, por ejemplo *retornarlo*; en tal caso:

```js
function mayor() {
  return Math.max(...prompt('Ingresa los números, separados por comas','').split(','));
}
```

Aunque no es buena idea agruparlo todo en una línea por motivos de legibilidad esta vez lo he escrito así por la simpleza del código, aunque la verdad se debería haber recogido primero la respuesta del usuario en una **variable** y después proporcionárselos a la *función estática* de **Math**

Answer (score 3):

Para obtener el número mayor de un array ¡ya no es obligatorio escribir código que itere sobre el arreglo!

Para eso existe `Math.max()`. Teniendo un array de números, puedes obtener el mayor de ellos dos maneras.

### I. Con el operador de propagación (spread operator)

Con el nuevo [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Spread_operator) (ECMA Script 2015), obtener el máximo de un arreglo se vuelve mucho más fácil.

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
var max = Math.max(...arr);
```

---

### II. Con `Function.prototype.apply()` : recomendada para arreglos de gran tamaño

La siguiente función usa `Function.prototype.apply()` para encontrar el elemento mayor en un array numérico. `getMaxOfArray([1, 2, 3])` es equivalente a `Math.max(1, 2, 3)`, pero se puede usar `getMaxOfArray()` sobre arreglos construidos programáticamente de cualquier tamaño.

```
function getMaxOfArray(numArray) {
  return Math.max.apply(null, numArray);
}
```

---

#### Código:

```js
//Definimos un array para probar
var numArray = [1, 2, 3];

//Forma I
var max = Math.max(...numArray);
console.log(max);


//Forma II
var mayor=getMaxOfArray(numArray);
console.log(mayor);

function getMaxOfArray(numArray) {
  return Math.max.apply(null, numArray);
}
```

---

Ver: [Math.max en la documentación de MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/max)

Answer (score 0):

prueba con esto:

```
function mayor(
var max = 0;
var array = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] > max) {
            max = array[i];
        }
    }
    alert(max);
)
```

Comment: Hola. por favor si no lo hiciste mira [answer]. Aunque tu código soluciona el problema y es correcto, siempre se pide que las respuestas tengan un poco mas que solo código. Gracias por tu ayuda! Debido a eso, tu respuesta fue reportada como de baja calidad.

Comment: hola, soy nuevo en stackoverflow aveces entro a participar en el foro. Si hay una guía de como dar una respuesta correcta por favor agradecería mucho su apoyo!

Comment: usa el link que te pase [answer]

Answer (score 0):

mi respuesta no será en javascript, pero puedo hacerte en pseudocódigo, y podrás extrapolarla en Javascript.

La gracia, es mantener una variable que contenga el valor más alto en todo momento mientras se recorre el blucle. Mientras se recorre el blucle el nuevo valor se compara con dicha variable, y si es mayor se substituye, sino, simplemente se avanza. Al final del blucle tendrás guardado el valor más alto.

```
variable  numMaximo = -1;

for(int i = 0; i < arrayARecorrer.size() ; i++){
    si (arrayARecorrer[i]>numMaximo){
         numMaximo = arrayARecorrer[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Saludos**

Despues de

```
var c = ingresar.replace(new RegExp(',', "gi"), " ").split(" "),var v = c.length;
```

creas una variable donde guardaras el mayor; ejem:

```
var elMayor = Number(c[0]); /* Asumo que el array al menos tendrá un elemento y tomamos el primer elemento como el mayor */
```

claro esta que ademas que el presente considera que el array obtenido del Split tiene al menos un elemento; y todos corresponden a número; por ello no inclui verificación ni validación del dato antes de compararlo. En tu `for`:

```
for(j=0;j<v;j++){
  if (elMayor<Number(c[j]))
    elMayor=c[j];
}

alert(elMayor);
```

Que te sea de utilidad.

Answer (score 0):

podrías hacer esto:

```
function mayor(){
    var mayor,
          ingresados = prompt('Ingresa los números, separados por comas', '');

    ingresados.split(',');

    mayor = Math.max.apply(null, ingresados);
    return mayor;
}
```

La función retorna el número mayor del Array, espero y te sirva.